# udhcpc and VLAN settings on embedded systems

Tags: networking, scripts, dhcp, vlan

Is it a good idea to use a script for udhcpc linux busybox tool for configuring VLAN settings or is the purpose of this script related to dhcp protocol?

According to the manual of udhcpc there is an option to provide script path for configuring, but there is no info about VLAN settings.

In case of need to configure VLAN (like subnetwork of existing LAN) it will be a good idea to put some commands such as

```
vconfig add eth 0 1
...
```

inside of this script. After executing udhcpc command with this script, will VLAN also be configured?

Is this the correct input for this script?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that you are not going on the right way. Your computer must be already in the right VLAN before it will be able to make communication with the switch. Until your computer is set to the right vlan, you will not able to use a DHCP client in order to get an IP address.

You should use vlan tagging directly on the switch port instead.

Comment: thanks for reply, so, firstly VLAN have to be set, and then we can use udhcpc to obtain IP adress, its correct ?

Comment: yep, this correct !